# Что выгодней для оптимизации: анонимный объект, объект или структура?

Tags: c#, .net, оптимизация, структуры-данных, типы-данных

Имеется метод, который подсчитывает какое-то значение для каких-то сущностей. Для подсчёта значений производится выборки из бд целыми списками. Метод долго выполнялся и во время его рефакторинга у меня встал вопрос.

Например, у меня есть сущность `Box` с 30+ полями, из которых мне надо только `Id` (GUID виде string) и `Date` (DateTimeOffset?). Было это записано так:

```
var boxes = await _dbContext.Boxes.ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.Date, token);
```

*Уточню, что используется .NET Core версии 2.2.8 с Entity Framework Core.*

Посмотрев SQL код в логах, заметил, что EF вытягивает все поля сущности в запросе. Оно-то и логично, наверное, но не очевидно. Дополнив данный запрос `.Select()` я сократил SQL SELECT до двух полей:

```
var boxes = await _dbContext.Boxes.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Date })
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.Date, token);
```

Вот мы и подошли к саму вопросу: во что будет выгодней, в плане производительности, поместить поля в Select'е, если "это" в дальнейшем будет преобразовано во что-то иное?.. Приведу ещё пример с [`KeyValuePair`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netcore-2.2):

```
var boxes = await _dbContext.Boxes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset?>(x.Id, x.Date))
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.Date, token);
```

---

*P.S. Понимаю, что это может оказаться крупицей в оптимизации, меня всё же интересует как быть конкретно в этой ситуации. Поспрашивал у коллег и ответы не были однозначными, поэтому спрашиваю тут.*

*И если бы был не Dictionary после Select'а, а какой-нибудь список/массив, то правильнее, наверное, было бы всё-таки использовать обычный объект, для лучшей читабельности кода и его поддержки другими программистами.*

Comment: c точки зрения производительности между анонимным классом и своим классом разницы никакой. Анонимный класс это тот же класс, просто созданный компилятором для вас.

Comment: Кстати, разница может случиться в том плане, что `KeyValuePair` - структура, а не класс. Но тут будет вопрос класс vs структура.

Comment: по поводу использования анонимных классов - если вы получаете эти данные и используете в рамках одной функции, то городить классы не имеет смысла, можно обойтись анонимными. Если же вы эти данные хотите куда то передать или сохранить из функции, то тогда желательно сделать отдельный класс.

Comment: Вытянутые данные используется в одном методе, по факту, находится последняя дата для списка объектов. Эта дата есть в разных таблицах.

Comment: По поводу "логично, но неочевидно": `ToDictionaryAsync` не принимает Expression ни в одной из перегрузок, а значит, что в формировании запроса даже не может участвовать, следовательно EF даже знать не может, что пользователь запросил только два поля из 30. Поэтому первый запрос вытягивает сущности полностью. А по поводу классов, согласен с tym32167: в производительности разницы между анонимным классом и обычным в данном случае нет. Собственный класс лишь добавит читаемости, если на выходе запроса будет именно этот класс.

Comment: Думаю быстрее будет если отказаться от ORM в частности EntityFramework.

Comment: Для оптимизации лучше всего перейти на вызов заранее созданной хранимой процедуры, а в какую структуру вы поместите полученные данные дело десятое.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, не вариант, необходимо поддерживать 3 разные бд. Да и не в этом вопрос, если честно бд тут только упомянута, чтобы было понимание что работа с IQueryable происходит. Ваше предложении вообще никак в вопросу не относится.

Comment: @Bulson, нет возможности напрямую взаимодействовать с бд, опять же, вопрос не про бд или ORM. Как я вижу, тут все упускают ключевую деталь, что данные будут получаться через итератор и копироваться в память по разному в зависимости от использования ссылочного или значимого типа. Так что это не "десятое дело". И попрошу других комментатором абстрагироваться от БД.